# Generate composite hbase rowkey using Flume Serializer

Tags: hadoop, hbase, interceptor, flume, serialization

I have GIS data which looks like this -

```
'111, 2011-02-01 20:30:30, 116.50443, 40.00951'  
'111, 2011-02-01 20:30:31, 116.50443, 40.00951'  
'112, 2011-02-01 20:30:30, 116.58197, 40.06665'  
'112, 2011-02-01 20:30:31, 116.58197, 40.06665'
```

First column is `driver_id`, second is `timestamp`, third is `longitude` & fourth is `latitude`.

I am ingesting this type of data using Flume & my sink is HBase (type - `AsyncHBaseSink`).
By default the HBase assigns rowkey as first column (like 111). I want to create a composite rowkey (like combination of first two columns 111_2011-02-01 20:30:30).
I tried putting the required changes in '`AsyncHbaseLogEventSerializer.java`' but they were not reflected.

Please suggest how can I do the same.

Comment: composite rowkey should work and its normal to use such key. Can you please paste your code snippet of how are you doing this ?

Comment: please check the sample snippets, in my experience it should be possible (if you haven't done simple mistakes) :-)

Comment: :Was my answer helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite key should work in AsyncHbaseSerializer

Below is the sample code snippet.

Declare at class level `privae List<PutRequest> puts = null;`

```
 /**
     * Method joinRowKeyContent. (with EMPTY string separation)
     * 
      * Joiner is google guava class
     * @param objArray Object...
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    public static String joinRowKeyContent(Object... objArray) {
        return Joiner.on("").appendTo(new StringBuilder(), objArray).toString();
    }

 /**
     * Method preParePutRequestForBody.
     * 
     * @param rowKeyBytes
     * @param timestamp
     */
    private void preParePutRequest(final byte[] rowKeyBytes, final long timestamp) {
        // Process 

            LOG.debug("Processing ..." + Bytes.toString(rowKeyBytes));

        final PutRequest putreq = new PutRequest(table, rowKeyBytes, colFam, Bytes.toBytes("yourcolumn"), yourcolumnasBytearray, timestamp);
        puts.add(putreq);
    }
```

> Your get actions method looks like...

```
  @Override
        public List<PutRequest> getActions() {
//create rowkey like this
    final String rowKey = joinRowKeyContent(driver_id, timestamp, longitude , latitude);

    // call prepare put requests method here 
    final byte[] rowKeyBytes = Bytes.toBytes(rowKey);
                puts.clear();
     preParePutRequest(rowKeyBytes ,<timestamp>)
            return puts;
        }
```